# How to copy a record from one mongo collection to another mongo collection which are residing on different hosts which are accessible via ssh

Tags: bash, mongodb, mongo-shell

I have two Mongo Instances on different hosts (dev & stage) which can be accessible via ssh.

How to copy a record from the collection on **dev** instance and insert it into the **stage** instance?

**Steps tried:**

Tried to use mongodump and mongorestore, but not of any use because my mongo instances are accessible via SSH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using SSH, you can forward the MongoDB Ports to your local machine and use the usual MongoDB tools:

```
# first terminal
ssh -L27017:localhost:27017 mongohostA

# second terminal
ssh -L27018:localhost:27017 mongohostB

# third terminal
mongodump -h localhost -p 27017 ....
mongorestore -h localhost -p 27018 ....
```

What you are doing here is connect your local machines port `27017` to `mongohostA` MongoDB and your local machines port `27018` to `mongohostB` MongoDB. Then just use the MongoDB tools as usual, but configure different ports. Find documentation on those tools here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/

To have that working in a shellscript, we use [auto closing SSH tunnels](https://gist.github.com/scy/6781836). In this example we also use the `--query` option to `mongodump`:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -f -L27017:localhost:27017 mongohostA sleep 10

mongodump -h localhost -p 27017 -d databaseName -c collectionName \
          --query '{"_id": yourSingleDocumentID }' ....

ssh -f -L27018:localhost:27017 mongohostB sleep 10

mongorestore -h localhost -p 27018 ....
```

Comment: But how can I fetch a single record out of the collection and restore in another collection using normal mongo tools?

And can we achieve this using a bash script, instead of multiple terminals?

Comment: i added a script example.

Comment: Thanks its working, but made a small tweak to it as we are not able to restore to port 27018 (might be mongo is not reading from it).

So I killed the first process and then again connected using 27017 to the second host.

`#!/bin/bash
ssh -f -L27017:localhost:27017 mongohostA sleep 10

mongodump -h localhost -p 27017 -d databaseName -c collectionName \
          --query '{"_id": yourSingleDocumentID }' ....

lsof -ti:27017 | xargs kill -9

ssh -f -L27017:localhost:27017 mongohostB sleep 10

mongorestore -h localhost -p 27017 ....`